# I have an arg with type Option which i need to use in a http get request but Option type puts Some(T) into the formatted url

Tags: rust

This is the function for making the http get request and using selector to select a specific class of css.

```
pub async fn test(amount: Option<&str>, from: Option<&str>, to: Option<&str>) -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let url_final = format!("https://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/convert/?Amount={:?}&From={:?}&To={:?}", amount, from, to); //used debug cuz Option does not impl Display
}
```

output:

```
https://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/convert/?Amount=Some(1)&From=Some("USD")&To=Some("HUF")
```

basically my question is there any way to remove the `Some( )` and only leave the value.
This is what the http get request looks like btw:

```
let req = reqwest::get(url_final).await?;
```

FIXED with: `let url = url_final.replace("\"", "");`

Also added:

```
amount.unwrap_or_default from.unwrap_or_default to.unwrap_or_default
```

Comment: What do you want it to look like if the value is `None`?

Comment: `unwrap`, `unwrap_or`???

Comment: My problem is that the http get request doesen't work when it put's the some() into the url_final when formatting i want to take that part out if even possible.

Comment: I understand you don't want the `Some()` part, but `Option`s are allowed to be `None` so I'm asking what you want the url to look like in that case, where there is no value to print. Should the function return an error? Should it omit the whole query parameter? Or should the query parameter be set to an empty string? Or something else? I ask because on its face, querying like `?Amount=&From=&To=` doesn't look that useful to me.

Comment: It should return an error if it's none!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Debug` implementation for `Option<T>` will print the `Some` and `None` variant names. That's the point of `Debug`, which is what you'll get when you use `{:?}` in a format string.

You can use `unwrap_or("")` or `unwrap_or_default()`:

```
let url_final = format!(
    "https://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/convert/?Amount={}&From={}&To={}",
    amount.unwrap_or_default(),
    from.unwrap_or_default(),
    to.unwrap_or_default()
);
```

Given you are using `reqwest`, a nicer way to do this is to use a struct for your query parameters, and make use of `serde` to omit the `None` values:

```
use serde::Serialize;

#[derive(Serialize)]
#[serde(rename_all = "PascalCase")]
struct XeArgs<'a> {
    amount: Option<&'a str>,
    to: Option<&'a str>,
    from: Option<&'a str>,
}

let client = reqwest::Client::new();

let query = XeArgs {
    amount: None,
    to: Some("USD"),
    from: None,
};

let response = client
    .get("https://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/convert/")
    .query(&query)
    .send()
    .await?;
```

Comment: The problem is that this solution still leaves the "" around the values which is also bad because the values should just be the <value> not "<value>".

Comment: @akkunt That's because you're formatting with `"{:?}"`. Use `"{}"` as in my example for `Display` formatting instead.